# ssh -T git@github.com Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, octopress

I tried to push my blog (Octopress) to github and got this error:

```
MacBook-Air:octopress bdeely$ git push origin source
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I generated an SSH key, saved it, and even linked it with my GitHub account in the SSH key settings, but I went ahead and checked the status and got the same error:

```
MacBook-Air:.ssh bdeely$ ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

In addition to this, I checked [github's help page](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey), did the following and got this error message:

```
MacBook-Air:~ bdeely$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Does anyone know what is wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you check the permission of the two files in .ssh folder? They must have 600 permisions? How you generate the keys?

Answer (score 5):

On OSX, if you type

```
ssh-add -l
```

and you get back "no identities", that means your ssh agent does not have any identities loaded into it.  Oftentimes, when the mac reboots, you have no identities.

I add mine back after a re-boot by explicitly running

```
ssh-add
```

This loads a default identity from ~/.ssh/id_rsa

You can also use the ssh-add command with a specific identity

```
ssh-add ~/foo/bar/is_rsa
```

After you add your identies, you can seem them all listed by typing

```
ssh-add -l
```

Make sure you have at least one listed.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the commands:

```
    mkdir ~/.ssh //in case that the folder doesnt exist...
    cd ~/.ssh

    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremail@somewhere.gr"
    #hit enter when asks for file to save the key.
    #enter the passphrase
```

At last copy the **id_rsa.pub** into your github account.

Comment: Thanks Christos. 

I already created SSH keys, as stated above.

How would I add 600 permissions?

Comment: in linux OS you can with the following way: `cd ~/.ssh` and 
`chmod 600 id_rsa*`

Comment: How you copy-paste the id_rsa.pub into github account?

Comment: check out [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), if you havent find that already.

Comment: I found my problem...

In this section:
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa):

I accidentally entered text instead of simply hitting "enter"

This would have been an impossible error to find....

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Christos...it was a very bad error on my part.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your terminal:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

enter your passphrase if any and it should work. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you:

I was having the identical problem and about to take my own eyes out with insane frustration; nothing online led me to an answer and I was trying to use the `git push` command without specifying the URL exactly (which could also solve the problem I believe), so I didn't see how the connection was failing.

I had set up my `.ssh/config` correctly for two users with two different keys, even using `IdentitiesOnly yes` which is supposed to override `ssh-agent` that was automatically supplying the **WRONG** ssh identity.

I finally realized the problem as I examined the local repository configuration - it was the entry

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:{my-username}/{my-repo-name}.git
```

My configuration in `.ssh/config` file was using the same `HostName github.com` entry for both users and I'm completely new to all this so I didn't realize that to correctly override `ssh-agent`, I had to specify the exact URL or else the specific identities in my `.ssh/config` file would be ignored and the first key that `ssy-agent` listed (which was the wrong one my my case) would be used by default.

I fixed this by changing the local repo URL to `url = git@github-personal:{my-username}/{my-repo-name}.git`, where I had set `Host github-personal` as the identity in my `.ssh/config`.

Another way to solve this would be specifying the user in the URL in the `git push` command itself, or even better, a solution described here in a post AFTER solving this my own crappy way:

https://superuser.com/questions/272465/using-multiple-ssh-public-keys

I can't believe that no official source could offer a solution for or even properly explain this edge-case that seems really common (accessing two different github accounts from one machine with SSL).

Comment: Had a similar issue, just that in my case the issue in .ssh/config was with `Host *` definition of `IdentityFile`.  Once I commented `IdentityFile` then `ssh -T git@github.com` passed.  And in my case, I also had `IdentitiesOnly yes` defined (again under `Host *`) - but removing it or switching to `no` made no impact.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. The reason was that I moved the key-files to another folder; it worked successfully when I moved them back to where they were originally.